# Как сравнить два аудио файла

Tags: java, android, аудио

Я много искал как сравнить два аудио файла, но нигде не нашел пример такой задачи.

Есть приложение с аудио файлом (звонка двери). Я хочу запустить `service` прослушки звуков и сравнить с тем, что есть в приложении. Если кто-то позвонит в дверь, и звонок будет равен тому что есть в приложении, то сделать какое-то действие.

Как такое реализовать?

Comment: Увы, но абсолютно точное сравнение будет выдавать слишком много ложных срабатываний и задача не является такой простой, чтобы можно было кратко описать решение.

Answer (score 0):

Сам с таким не работал, но кажется, нашёл, что тебе нужно;
**Вариант 1:** Библиотека `musicg` позволяет сравнить два .wav-файла (лучше работать именно с ними - сжатие вроде .mp3 только усложнит задачу) (подробнее - на [английском StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358055/java-compare-two-audio-files-with-fingerprint))

**Вариант 2:** Библиотека `marsyas`, к тому же, лучше подходящая для android ([там же](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213090/compare-two-sound-in-android))

p.s. И, да, стоит поискать на английском - часто, материалы по вопросам вроде CV, или сравнения аудио в принципе не переведены